# Does Dr. Mario: Miracle Cure support inter-regional multiplayer?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, dr-mario-miracle-cure

Since I have Japanese 3DS, and my sister has a European one, I was wondering if *Dr. Mario: Miracle Cure* (*Dr. Mario* ギャクテン！特効薬) supports local multiplayer across regions?

From what I understand, this seems to depend on the game; [some seem to support inter-regional multiplayer, while others don't](http://www.gaijingamers.com/showthread.php?t=6417). I haven't yet found anything about this specific game, since it's been released only recently.

If I get the Japanese one and she gets the German one, will we be able to do feverish battle against each other in the multiplayer mode?